# MySQL Get Time of Old Record Insert?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database which contains all of the users for my application. Unfortunately, when I launched my application, I didn't think to include a column which tracked the time at which a particular user signed up, and now I wish I had (bad idea, yes indeed).

Is there, by any shred of luck, a way that MySQL tracks when a particular record is inserted (such as in record metadata???), and would allow me to grab it and insert in into a new dedicated column for this purpose?

I am running on a shared cPanel host, so I doubt I have access to the MySQL logs.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to look in your log.

Comment: @njk I would have about 900 entries to update after I would check the log. And I am on a shared cPanel host. :((

Comment: Is there any other table with user actions that would at least get you a ball bark of their date?

Comment: @njk I could. It is an online book exchange, and I could get the date at which they published their first book. However, if possible, I would like to be more precise.

Comment: If you are very lucky, you can get httpd logs and see when registration forms where filled, hopping you can distinct each user with something like the IP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you have binary logging enabled will you be able to trace exact times for the transaction.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html

Its not just for replication, but also a form of transactional recording in case of emergency.