# Insertion time of a row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get the information about the **`insertion time`** of a particular row in a table ?

Suppose, I've the following ***table (user)***:

```
      ________________
      | ID  | name   |
      |_____|________|
      | 1   |    tom |
      | 2   |   brad |
      |_____|________|
```

Now, I want to know **when the second row(2,brad) was inserted** .

Is it possible? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Please go through this link. It might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469270/mysql-get-time-of-old-record-insert)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select table_schema,table_name,max_time 
from information_schema.tables t1 JOIN 
 (select MAX(t2.create_time) AS maximum_time FROM 
  information_schema.tables t2 where  
  table_schema ='user') as t3  
on t1.create_time = t3.max_time;
```

This will give the time of the last insert time in your table.

**On a side note:**

You can add one more column to your table and store the time in that column when the record was inserted. This will help you identify when the specific record was inserted.

Something like this:-

```
insert into yourtable(ID, name, CreatedTime)
values(2,'Brad',now())
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `trigger`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

it's a little complex, but it does work!

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_user_insert BEFORE INSERT ON user
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    -- When an insertion occurs, you do your work here with SQL
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```