# how to know the date of insertion of record in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, insert, phpmyadmin

I am using `phpMyAdmin` for my project and I have a table without `date/datetime` field.

I am wondering if there's a way to know when I inserted each record on the database

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Get Time of Old Record Insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469270/mysql-get-time-of-old-record-insert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While designing your database if you forgot to keep an extra field to store the insertion time of a row then you have only one option left to know the the insertion time.

**But the condition is you must have binary logging enabled prior to it.**

> [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html)

You may check if binary logging is enabled in your part by executing this query :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';
```

**Further Note:**

And from now on you may keep an extra field which will track the insertion time of each row.

**Change your table design :**

Add an extra field in your table with datatype "timestamp/datetime" with default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and on update `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: thanks for you answer, unfortunately i have `log_bin` field disabled

Comment: You are welcome! :) you may enable binary logging from now on. [Check this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445678/binary-log-error-in-mysql)