# Get Last First Inserted zero entry mysql

Tags: mysql

Have three columns

```
ID  User     Quantity   Date
1    x        0       2016-01-01
2    x        2       2016-01-02
3    x        0       2016-01-03
4    x        0       2016-01-04
5    xx       0       2016-01-01
6    xx       2       2016-01-02
7    xx       0       2016-01-03
8    xx       8       2016-01-04
9    xx       0       2016-01-06
10   xx       0       2016-01-04
```

Now How do i get user wise first of the latest sequence of 0 entry for x user ID=3,xx ID=9.

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE ID = 9 OR ID = 3` ?

Comment: No.. I need the query based on user name...Need all the users or singe user with their last first inserted zero record details

Comment: For x user, how id is 3 as the last inserted 0 is by id 4.

Comment: Please outline your question clearly, what exactly do you mean by "last first" ?

Comment: Show us a query. What did you try?

Comment: Guys, it's really not that hard to understand. The first of the latest sequence of 0 in quantity...

Comment: For x user need to to find when quantity has become zero...For x user there are three zeros at ID 1,3,4 But at Id 2 we have > 0 quantity...So we need to neglect ID=1. rest 3,4 are there...in that first record we need to take that is Id = 3.

Comment: So what would "last first" it be for user "xx"? ID 7 or ID 9? They have the same date. Are you sequencing by date or by ID?

Comment: yes fancyPants...its first of last sequence of zeros

Comment: according which order? inserted date?

Comment: @friedemann_bachConsider Id...there i have put some random date....its ID9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367982/how-to-know-the-date-of-insertion-of-record-in-sql

Comment: @mcNets it will give Last one in the last sequence of zeros...Not first

Comment: please improve your question by adding the expected result.

Comment: Am expecting all the users with their ID,Name and date of first of the latest sequence of 0 in quantity...
User,ID,Date
x,3,2016-01-03
xx ,9,   2016-01-06

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complex, because we need to find the last not 0 entry for a name. (I would naturally tend to sort by date, but you said ID is what to go for.)

```
   SELECT t1.name, max(t1.id) as check_id FROM table t1 WHERE quantity > 0 GROUP BY name
```

Now you can get the lowest number for each name that is higher than the given check_id:

```
SELECT name, min(t2.id) FROM table t2
JOIN (SELECT t1.name, max(t1.id) as check_id FROM table t1 WHERE quantity > 0 GROUP BY name) as a ON a.name=t2.name
WHERE t2.quantity = 0 AND t2.id > a.id
GROUP BY t2.name
```

There's one problem. It will exclude everyone with only 0 quantity. If this could happen you need another query with the following code (to get only 0 values)

```
SELECT name, min(id) as check_id, sum(quantity) as qty_sum FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING qty_sum = 0
```

Comment: it works. And i keep your suggestion while posting the question. ty.

Comment: @Manoj Would you than please upvote my answer and mark it as an correct

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the first step is to identify the last dataset with a positive quantity by each user. The lowest ID of all following datasets would be what you seek. In other words, you need to look for MAX(ID) of all positive entries and apply MIN(ID) on all entries with a higher ID. In one query:

```
SELECT `User`, MIN(`ID`) FROM t `mainquery`
WHERE `ID` > (
  SELECT MAX(`ID`) FROM t `subquery`
  WHERE `Quantity` > 0 AND `mainquery`.`User` = `subquery`.`User`
  GROUP BY `User`
)
GROUP BY `User`
```

With the data from your example, this query returns:

```
User    MIN(`ID`)
x       3
xx      9
```

Test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c487/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT t1.user,min(t1.id) as ID,quantity,date from tablename t1
JOIN
(SELECT MAX(id) as qid,user FROM tablename WHERE Quantity>0 GROUP BY user) t2
ON t2.user=t1.user
WHERE t1.id>t2.qid
AND t1.Quantity=0
GROUP BY t1.user
```